# Пунктуация при однородных членах с двойным союзом и союзом и

Tags: пунктуация

Засомневалась в постановке знаков при выполнении тренировочного задания №16 (подготовка к ЕГЭ).

На разных сайтах предложение из "Капитанской дочки" Пушкина по-разному оформлено пунктуационно.
Варианты такие:

***1. Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию(,?) и благополучием ...

2. Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию и благополучием ...***

Составители задания выбрали второй вариант с одной запятой.

Я взяла свою "Капитанскую дочку" **(А.С. Пушкин. Сочинения в трёх томах. М.,"Художественная литература", 1986)** . Читаю:
*"Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию, и благополучием тех, которые..."* - **Две** запятые. **Проблемная - после слова СОВЕСТИЮ.**

**Ставится запятая или не ставится? Почему?** ***Не только жизнию, но и совестию (?) и благополучием...***

**Я считаю, что запятая должна быть одна.** Союз ***не только..., но и...*** - это двойной союз, вторая его часть *но и...* присоединяет пару ***совестию и благополучием***, в которой используется одиночный союз ***И***.

Comment: Здесь есть подобное предложение. Ситуация подобная рассматривается. http://ktvd.ru/sojuz-ne-tolko-no-i/

Answer (score 2):

> Я взяла свою "Капитанскую дочку". Читаю: "Они готовы резаться и
> жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию, и благополучием тех,
> которые..." - Две запятые. Проблемная - после слова СОВЕСТИЮ.
>
> Ставится запятая или не ставится? Почему? Не только жизнию, но и
> совестию (?) и благополучием...

Возможны оба варианта. Но смысл у этих вариантов, на мой взгляд, будет разный:

если поставить запятую, то жертвовать "они" готовы своей совестью,

а если не поставить — то совестью "тех"...

Я бы выбрал вариант с запятой, но вот в Нацкорпусе (и, видимо, в собрании сочинений) запятой нет. Увы...

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

В первом издании "Капитанской дочки" (в "Современнике"), как уже говорилось в этой теме, запятой перед "и благополучием тех" не было. Но в последующих переизданиях "К. д." рассматриваемое предложение стало печататься и с запятой.  Видимо, редакторы хотели разорвать сочетание "совестию и благополучием тех": всё-таки совесть-то должна была болеть после убийства на дуэли, в первую очередь, не у "тех", а у оставшихся в живых дуэлянтов. При наличии запятой такой смысл угадывается легче.

Печаталось рассматриваемое предложение и с запятой, и без запятой и в ХIХ веке, так же печатается и сейчас.

Не согласен с прозвучавшим в ответе Sharon утверждением, что "запятой нет и в академических изданиях Пушкина". Встречается и в академических. См. (А.С. Пушкин. Полное собрание сочинений в 10 томах. Том шестой. Изд. АН СССР. 1949): https://books.google.ru/books?id=0FMYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B8+%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22+1949&dq=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B8+%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%22+1949&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5ze7G9__sAhUhmYsKHeIeCnQQ6AEwA3oECAQQAg

Ну а зачем включать это предложение в задания по подготовке к ЕГЭ — при наличии столь разных подходов к его пунктуационному оформлению в авторитетных изданиях! — на этот вопрос, думаю, и сами составители задания не ответят...

Answer (score 2):

**1. О закрытых и открытых однородных рядах**

Можно ли в принципе поставить запятую?  Да, и это следует из теории открытых и закрытых однородных рядов.

Из Грамматики-80

§ 2070. Сочинительный ряд может состоять из потенциально неограниченного количества членов или только из двух членов. Это зависит от характера отношений. Существуют **открытые**, перечисляющие ряды, т. е. такие, которые допускают пополнение новыми членами (В саду растут груши, яблони, сливы...), и **закрытые** ряды, т. е. такие, которые не допускают пополнения новыми членами при тех же отношениях (В саду растут **не только яблони, но и груши**).

§ 2071. Любой член сочинительного ряда может, в свою очередь, сам представлять собою **ряд словоформ**: Она взглянула на него и улыбнулась, но не веселой и радостной, а испуганной, жалостной улыбкой (Л. Толст.). В речи свободно возникают различные **комбинации открытых и закрытых рядов** как союзных, так и бессоюзных.

Итак,  ряд с союзом *не только ..., но и ...* является **закрытым**, но допускает  представление второго однородного члена в виде ряда. Ряд может быть открытым (повторяющийся союз И…И) или закрытым (одиночный союз И). Это видно и по возможности перечислительной интонации для второй части предложения.

(1) *Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, **но и совестию и благополучием...***

(2) *Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, **но и совестию, и благополучием...*

2. **Есть ли семантическая разница**?

Варианты различаются тем, что при постановке запятой и перечислительной интонации ударение падает **на каждый однородный член**. Таким образом логически **подчеркивается важность** каждого из них. Если же считать, что союз И одиночный, то "совестию и благополучием" рассматривается **как нечто единое,** что более **вероятно и естественно**.   Откуда взялся вариант с запятой, не очень понятно, но грамматически и интонационно он возможен.

**О различии** одиночного союза И и повторяющегося союза И...И

"Повторяющийся союз И...И **подчеркивает,** что семантическое отношение, им выражаемое, затрагивает все без исключения однородные члены. В предложении с одиночным союзом И однородные члены тоже участвуют в сочинении, однако этот смысл не подчеркнут; его **подчеркивание** как раз и составляет семантическую специфику повторяющегося союза. [http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#21](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#21)

**3. Авторский текст**

«Капитанская дочка» была опубликована за месяц до гибели автора в издававшемся им журнале «Современник» под видом записок покойного Петра Гринёва.
Текст этого можно посмотреть по ссылке http://lib.pushkinskijdom.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=9136

Итак у Пушкина  нет запятой: (1) *Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию и благополучием...*  Кстати, запятой нет и в академических изданиях Пушкина.

Answer (score 1):

> Я считаю, что запятая должна быть одна. Союз не только..., но и... -
> это двойной союз, вторая его часть но и... присоединяет пару совестию
> и благополучием, в которой используется одиночный союз И.

Совершенно верно, по смыслу тут больше подходит именно такая трактовка. Можно немного по-другому трактовать, считая первое "и" усилительной частицей. Тем более, что во времена пушкина она часто опускалась - и таким образом в состав союза не входила. Но результат будет тот же самый. Запятая тут потребна одна.

А вот другая трактовка, которая предполагает, что "и... и..." - повторяющийся союз и таким требует дополнительноуй запятой здесь сомнительна. По грамматике такое возможно (почему нет?), но смысл, как сказал slava1947, уже немного другой. Этот "другой смысл" я, правда понимаю совсем не так, как он. Запятая означала бы, что жертвовать "они" готовы "совестию и благополучием" только всем сразу, а не по отдельности.  Это, конечно, отчасти субъективное врсприятие, но я готов его пояснить на простом примере.

***Можете положить в компот не только яблоки, но и груши(,) и сливы.***

По-моему смысл разный - с запятой и без. С запятой разрешается добавить смесь из груш и слив, без запятой можно **не только** эту смесь, ***но и*** только груши **или** только сливы. Вот как-то так.

То же и у Пушкина. Нет?

(+)====

Подумавши, решил добавить.

@slava1947 опирается на полный пушкинский вариант фразы.

> Они готовы резаться и жертвовать не только жизнию, но и совестию и
> благополучием тех, которые...

Возможно, я не совсем его понял, но я не могу взять в толк, как и почему наличие или отсутствие запятой сказывается на принадлежности благополучия и совести. Благополучие - оно всегда "тех, которые", а совесть - своя, ну просто по смыслу иного не дано. Запятая этого не меняет. В нашем случае - точно.
Хотя, конечно, кто его знает, как воспринимались эти пунктуационные тонкости во времена Пушкина?

(++)====

Мое кредо требует прокомментировать, коль уж началась этакая дискуссия,  еще и развернутый ответ @Sharon. Но я просто потерялся, не могу уследить за её мыслью. Похоже, что мы в корне по-разному понимаем проблему. По мне так разговоры о закрытых и открытых рядах тут вообще не к месту. В нашей фразе ряд всегда открытый, есть ли там эта запятая, нет ли её... Закрытость этого ряда означала бы, что ***ничем, кроме явно перечисленного*** "они" жертвовать ***не готовы***. Ну абсурд же?! Тогда к чему эти все рассуждения у Sharon?